# Compile NetBeans project from command line by using Ant

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I have a NetBeans project I would like to compile from the command line. There are many other questions on StackOverflow about how to do so, but they explain how to compile the project using commands like `javac src/*.java`.

I haven't changed my NetBeans project's build settings. **By default**, how can I compile my project from the command line using Ant? Once I've built my project, where is the compiled file located, and what format is it in (i.e., .class files, one .jar file, etc.)?

(I understand that asking how to use Ant to compile my project in general is too broad of a question. That's why I'm specifically asking about how to compile using NetBean's default configuration for a project.)

I'm using NetBeans 8.0.2.

Comment: It looks like I can run `ant jar` to run Ant and build my project. But once I've run it, I can't find the compiled program. I'm expecting to find it in the `dist` in my project's root directory, but it's not there...

Comment: I was able to fix the problem with my .jar file not appearing in dist/ by copying my project's source, deleting the NetBeans project, and recreating it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514672/netbeans-is-no-longer-generating-a-jar-file-for-code-that-it-used-to

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ant compile` Compiles the project (.class files are placed in the build/classes folder)

`ant jar` Compiles the project (see above) and builds a JAR ( located in dist/ )

If that doesn't work for you, check `ant`'s output for errors. (Is the JAVA_HOME Variable set properly?)

Answer (score 3):

I'm totally agnostic IDE developer. After several frustrating years trying to emerge "netbeans ant config" to something usable from command line I became to create a wrapper for netbeans ant.

https://github.com/albfan/ant-netbeans

By now you can:

- detect defined targets with standard

$ ant <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>

- Rely on project will honor `JDK_HOME`

and most important

- Expect `all` ant target to complete smoothly, passing test and whatever stuff implied.