# Given that NetBeans is installed, how can I use ant from the command-line (on Windows)?

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, ant, netbeans-8

I have NetBeans 8.0.2 installed on my Windows 7 (64-bit) machine. I have also the JDK installed (Java SE Development Kit 8 update 66 (64-bit)).

I want to run `ant` from the command line, but the closest I think I've come to getting it to run is the following:

```
java -jar "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\extide\ant\lib\ant.jar"
```

but I got the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.Main
```

I also tried the following, thinking that `Main.class` might be inside `ant.jar`, but got the same error:

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\extide\ant\lib\ant.jar" -jar "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\extide\ant\lib\ant.jar"
```

I've spent at least an hour searching online and StackOverflow for the anser. The closest I've found is [Compile NetBeans project from command line by using Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007573/compile-netbeans-project-from-command-line-by-using-ant), but it assumes that `ant` is accessible from the command line already.

Comment: I figured it out. See below. Additional answers are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## To set up `ant` to work from the command line

1. Add `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\extide\ant\bin` to your PATH
2. Add the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` with the value `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66` (adjust this if you end up using a different version, of course).

#### Now that it is set up, simply use `ant` from the command line normally.

To rebuild the project, for example, simply do the following:

1. Open a new command prompt
2. Go to the project directory
3. Type `ant clean jar`